# Cannot Connect Two Monitors

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, acer

I have an acer aspire desktop with a g-force graphics card. I have two monitors connected, one into the graphics card, and the other into the motherboard, however the monitor connected to the graphics card is never recognized. I have run out of ideas, has any one else had the same problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Cannot Connect Two Monitors**

You need to try to install the drivers for your graphics card

Try This and just pick your graphics card and your version of Linux and language
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

If you dot know what Nvidia graphics you have just pick option 2
this works for all Nvidia Graphics card and that how you install the drivers.

Once have you done that the Operating System should have detected the monitors and Graphics Card.

If this doesn't work just go into your Graphics Card Properties in your Nvidia Software that you have install and try to fix or just reset the defaults or just simple troubleshoot the problem.

if this Doesn't work just tried to re-install Ubuntu

if also dont work just try to read the help for graphics of Nvidia 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

if you cannot find your problem or fix it, the problem might be that your hardware doesn't support the version of the Ubuntu that you have try to upgrade it or just wait for Ubuntu 12.04 long term support that is coming out in march 2012 and by then they will have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you install the nvidia drivers? Once installed they give you the option of turning on the second monitor.

See this for installation help.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Once installed run to turn on the second moniter.
gksudo nvidia-settings